# How to make sure the application is installed on a spot ec2 instance every time a new instance is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

when bid a spot ec2 instance, it can be terminated anytime and a new instance could be created as well. How can I make sure the new instance includes all the configuration and application I installed? Do I need to make use any other services of aws to ensure that?

Comment: You can always specify your AMI when you request the spot instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Spot hibernate feature if you are using an EBS-backed instance and using a fleet request.  The way this work is upon interruption, Spot will stop the instance and persist the state to the EBS root volume including RAM.   Then when Spot is able to launch the instance state according to the fleet policy the state will be restored and the instance goes upon its happy way.  Further reading on [Spot interruption behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#interruption-behavior)

Note, that during the interruption you instance will be unreachable.  Also, instance could take a while to be restored waiting for a Spot instance, but in experience the wait is minimal.

A few recommendation if you this features

- Use EBS encrypted volumes because your RAM is stored on EBS during hibernation.
- Use as many instance classes as possible to increase your chance of getting a Spot.  For example: if you are using m4.large. (2, 8) then you could also include m5large, c4.xlarge, and c5.xlarge.  The reason I selected c4 and c5 in xlarge instead of large is because the they have similar memory size as the m4.large.  And I'm assuming your instance is rightsized for vCPU and RAM size.
- Make sure you follow these [instruction on preparing your instance for hibernation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#prepare-for-instance-hibernation)

Answer (score 1):

When you launch stand-alone on-spot instances and it gets terminated, you need to launch it again manually. To make sure every time a new on-spot instance launches, put it in Autoscaling group and mention your required configuration in launch configuration.

[Launching Spot Instances in Your Auto Scaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-launch-spot-instances.html)

To make sure your application is installed every time you create a new instance, use codedeploy along with autoscaling which will use launch configuration to spin new instance and deploy the new application on your newly created instance.

[AWS CodeDeploy and Auto Scaling Integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/under-the-hood-aws-codedeploy-and-auto-scaling-integration/)

Answer (score 1):

You can always associate your own AMI when you request a spot instance as mentioned here

[Spot Instance Requests - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#using-spot-instances-request)

If you want to preserve any data, then you must set DeleteOnTermination as false for your EBS volume. More on it here

[Configure AMIs for Use With Spot Instances that Preserve EBS Volumes](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ami-preserve-ebs-spot/)